# How to validate the value of a parameter in the routes in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing in ASP.NET MVC with C# and I have an action declared like this:

```
public FileResult ViewImage (int ImageFileItemId, 
                             int MaxWidth, 
                             int MaxHeight, 
                             bool FixedWidthHeight, 
                             string JpegQuality)
```

I would like to validate that the parameter `FixedWidthHeight` is objectively `true` or `false`. If it is not, I will not find the action and there won't be an error, like 'error param value'.

I've heard that with the 'constrains' parameter you can validate that, but how?

Many times our clients write things like `https://.../ViewImage?ImageFileItemId= 6654&MaxWidth=800&MaxHeight=400&FixedWidthHeight=Trutes`. Normally the action returns an image, in this scenario it gives an error. The idea is to send a 404, because Google and other websites recognize the URL as valid. So for Google our page is wrong.

Comment: Many times our clients write things like "https://.../ViewImage?ImageFileItemId= 6654&MaxWidth=800&MaxHeight=400&FixedWidthHeight=Trutes", the action returns an image, it gives an error but the idea is to send a 404, because google and other they recognize the url as valid and for google our page is wrong.

Comment: I would use 403 instead of 404. Indicating that the request is understood, but you do not want to fulfill it , for reasons explained in the body of the response.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable this scenario, you should declare the `FixedWidthHeight` parameter to be a string, and parse it to a boolean yourself.

In pseudo code:

```
public FileResult ViewImage (int ImageFileItemId, 
                             int MaxWidth, 
                             int MaxHeight, 
                             string FixedWidthHeight, 
                             string JpegQuality)
{
    bool fixed;

    if (Boolean.TryParse(FixedWidthHeight, out fixed))
    {
        // Process the request normally
        // Where the 'fixed' variable holds the parsed value
    }
    else
    {
       // Return a 404, 403, 'parameter error' or something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I try to do the same but my boss feels that there is a better solution, since there are other actions that have the same problem and he does not want to pass everything to string, if you have any other idea it is welcome, regards

Comment: "[Route("Site/ViewImage/{FixedWidthHeight:bool}")]" sabes como hacer algo como esto?